# Combine Telerik for WPF Theme with my custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, styles, basedon

In my WPF application, I have a combo-box that changes themes upon selection changed:

```
private void OnThemeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as RadComboBox;
        if (sender == null) return;
        switch (comboBox.SelectedIndex)//@TODO - Turn to enum: 0 = Summer and etc 
        {
            case 0:
                SwitchToSummerTheme();
                break;
            case 1:
                SwitchToOffice2016Theme();
                break;
            case 2:
                SwitchToGreenTheme();
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the switch theme methods look like this:

```
private void SwitchToGreenTheme()
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        AddCommonResources();
    }
```

Same for SwitchToOffice2016Theme method:

```
private void SwitchToOffice2016Theme()
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2016;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        AddCommonResources();
    }
```

Now the AddCommonResources method adds my own Resource Dictionary that is going to contain my own custom style:

```
 private void AddCommonResources()
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Common;component/XamlResources/CustomResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });

    }
```

Now, in one of my views, I have a RadRadioButton as the following:

```
<telerik:RadRadioButton GroupName="a" x:Name="btn_move"
 Command="{Binding OnMoveCommand}" Content="{DynamicResource MoveString}" 
Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,3" Style="{StaticResource btn_menu_RadRadio}"/>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is:

```
<Style x:Key="btn_menu_RadRadio" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadRadioButton}"
**BASED ON CURRENT THEME (GREEN/OFFICE2016/SUMMER)** >
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
</Style>
```

How do I achieve this based on behaviour? I mean, I don't have the Resource name like:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource currentTelerikTheme}"
```

How can I achieve that? Tell WPF to be based on the current Theme style of Telerik (which can be Green/Office2016/Summer)

Answer (score 0):

Posting here the answer I got from the Telerik team:

> The dependency's name will remain the same across different Telerik themes. Therefore, you only need to use the single resource name.
>   To update your code so that it it is works when theme changes, do the following:

1 - Use BasedOn="{StaticResource RadRadioButtonStyle}"

2 - Change your Style assignment from StaticResource to DynamicResource